# MYSQL TIMESTAMP error code 1292 when loading table from file

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column "date_created" where I have tried type as both DATETIME and TIMESTAMP.

I set the default for this filed to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I have a cvs file from which I want to load data into the table where the value of the column date_created is blank.

When I load the file into the table I get an error code 1292 Incorrect Datetime Value

Comment: @Barmar he doesn't values for the column, so best to ignore it completely.

Comment: @Barmar He said the values for date_created were blank.

Comment: Missed that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include all columns for the target table in your CSV if you have a means of calculating them on the fly or MySQL will do it for you through a DEFAULT.

One approach to this would, therefore, be to remove the date_created column from your CSV file entirely and have the DEFAULT auto-generated as part of the LOAD DATA process. As you indicate, you have no values for this column anyway and the column will default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so this seems a reasonable approach.

Assuming a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Your CSV would, therefore, only contain the values for columns `a` and `b` and your LOAD DATA statement would be something like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  "yourfilename" INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (a,b);
```

or, if you want to be a bit explicit:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  "yourfilename" INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (a,b) SET id = NULL, date_created = NOW();
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you accept the answer you can close out the question.